# I can't assign a function of random numbers to appear when I enter the variable I set it as

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have created the below code so that the computer plays 3 different random outcomes

```
function computerPlay() {
        let computerRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

        if (computerRandomNumber === 0) {
            return "rock";
        } else if (computerRandomNumber === 1) {
            return "paper";
        } else(computerRandomNumber === 2)
        return "scissors";
    }
```

So far so good!, then I want to run another function where there will be player VS computer

```
 function playRound() {
       
        if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "rock") {
            return "It's a tie! Ties are lame and so are you for tying."
        } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "paper") {
            return "Loooooser looooser nia nia nia! Paper wrapped your rock and threw it in the bin!"
        } etc. etc.
```

I have declared these two variables for player and computer so that the above function works.

```
 let playerSelection = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
        let computerSelection = computerPlay();
```

When I console.log(computerSelection), I always get the same result and no random values, but when I console log computerPlay() it works just fine and I am getting random outcomes. Why is this happening to me? :(

Below is the whole code I have written so far

```
 function computerPlay() {
        let computerRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

        if (computerRandomNumber === 0) {
            return "rock";
        } else if (computerRandomNumber === 1) {
            return "paper";
        } else(computerRandomNumber === 2)
        return "scissors";
    }

    let playerSelection = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    let computerSelection = computerPlay();


    function playRound() {
       
        if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "rock") {
            return "It's a tie! Ties are lame and so are you for tying."
        } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "paper") {
            return "Loooooser looooser nia nia nia! Paper wrapped your rock and threw it in the bin!"
        } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
            return "Bravoooo you made it! Rock smashed the scissors! "
        } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") {
            return "Bravoooo you made it! Paper wrapped the rock and threw it in the bin! "
        } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "paper") {
            return "It's a tie! Ties are lame and so are you for tying. "
        } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
            return "Loooooser looooser nia nia nia! Scissors cut through your paper and made it look like an ugly origami swan"
        } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "rock") {
            return "Loooooser looooser nia nia nia! Rock smashed the scissors. "
        } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") {
            return "Bravoooo you made it! Scissors cut through paper and made it look like an ugly origami swan"
        } else(playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "scissors")
        return "It's a tie! Ties are lame and so are you for tying. "
    }
```

Comment: `else(computerRandomNumber === 2)` has an useless expression in it, and is very misleading. It doesn't cause a bug here, but should be fixed.

Comment: You need to repeat the assignment to get a new computer play.

Comment: Do you actually select a value out of `playerSelection = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]`? Because the way you posted this it seems like you're comparing the value of the full array to the option strings

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks so much for the tip, duly noted

Comment: @Barmar ok, how do I do that though?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I was thinking of making a prompt afterward so the user can select one of each

Comment: Just do `computerSelection = computerPlay();` in each round of the game.

Comment: Is `let computerSelection = computerPlay();` called within a function or block?

Comment: @AndreasPagonisSastre, ok, but `playerSelection === "rock"` will always return false if `playerSelection` is an array, this can also cause you to always get the same result if you have a catch all `else` clause

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I have made all 9 possible outcomes, I just didn't want to write them all down because it would take too much space :P

Comment: @Coll Have literally tried everything, global scope, function scope, const, let result is always the same if not an error

Comment: Post all of the code together so it is readable `playerSelection` looks like an array so not sure how an array can equal a string

Comment: Can you post the minimal reproducible code? This sounds like a block variable declaration issue.

Comment: @Coll I posted the entire code as to what I have written already

Answer (score 0):

You assign a variable once and never change it.

if you want the computer to make a decision on each round, you could write something like this:

```
function computerPlay() {
    let computerRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

    if (computerRandomNumber === 0) {
        return "rock";
    } else if (computerRandomNumber === 1) {
        return "paper";
    } else {
        return "scissors";
    }
}

let playerSelectionVariants = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

function playRound() {
   
    let computerSelection = computerPlay();
    let playerSelection = /* request user input from playerSelectionVariants */

    if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "rock") {
        return "It's a tie! Ties are lame and so are you for tying."
    } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "paper") {
        return "Loooooser looooser nia nia nia! Paper wrapped your rock and threw it in the bin!"
    } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
        return "Bravoooo you made it! Rock smashed the scissors! "
    } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") {
        return "Bravoooo you made it! Paper wrapped the rock and threw it in the bin! "
    } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "paper") {
        return "It's a tie! Ties are lame and so are you for tying. "
    } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
        return "Loooooser looooser nia nia nia! Scissors cut through your paper and made it look like an ugly origami swan"
    } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "rock") {
        return "Loooooser looooser nia nia nia! Rock smashed the scissors. "
    } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") {
        return "Bravoooo you made it! Scissors cut through paper and made it look like an ugly origami swan"
    } else {
        return "It's a tie! Ties are lame and so are you for tying. "
    }
}
```